# SO Careers: not being able to confirm my OpenID

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, login, openid

I got an invitation for SO Careers, but I'm not being able to confirm my OpenID by clicking the "LogIn" button, and I'm being redirected here

https://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/openidconfirm

I thought it was some connection related issue, so I tried some more times but the result is the same, it takes some time (something like 20 secs) to show me the error page. I've never had any problem to connect with my google credentials to StackExchange.

If I can help you with some details, let me know!

Comment: Try doing it in Private/Incognito mode of the browser. Any luck?

Comment: Damn! you're a real wizard! It did the job!

Comment: Cheers, made it into an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something with your existing logged in user conflicted with something on Careers end, so logging in while browsing in Private/Incognito mode might "solve" this problem.

After that initial step you might be able to use your ordinary browser session, assuming your Careers account was created successfully.

If still no luck, a Careers dev will have to take a look at the core problem, it's past my own skills.